# How to fix else without if?

Tags: java

I'm trying to see if two numbers fall in between March 20 (3, 20) and June 20 (6, 20) and if the days in that period of time. 
(Checking to see if a day is a Spring day or not).

```
public class IsaSpringDay {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      int m = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int d = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

      if (m >= 3 && m <= 6) {
         if (m = 3) {
            if (d >= 20) {
               System.out.println(true);
            } else {
               System.out.println(false);
            } else if (m = 6) {
               if (d <= 20) {
                  System.out.println(true);
               } else System.out.println(false);
            }
         } else {
            System.out.println(false);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The error message is

```
ISD.java:13: error: 'else' without 'if' 
            } else if (m = 6) {
              ^
1 error
```

Comment: You cannot have an else if after an else statement. The else statement should be the last block in the if- elseif - elseif... -else conditions.

Comment: It's simply not valid Java, pure and simple. Study the tutorials on how to use if and if/else blocks and you'll understand how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have messed up the nesting of your if statements. The last `else` should correspond to the first `if`, and the `else if (m == 6)` case should correspond to the `if (m == 3)` case. You also missed the case of `m` being 4 or 5, in which `true` should be printed. And remember: use `==` to compare integers, not `=`.

```
    if (m >= 3 && m <= 6) {
        if (m == 3) {
            if (d >= 20) {
                System.out.println(true);
            } else {
                System.out.println(false);
            }
        } else if (m == 6) {
            if (d <= 20) {
                System.out.println(true);
            } else {
                System.out.println(false);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(true); // you missed this print statement
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(false);
    }
```

You can also do this with `java.time.MonthDay`:

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.of(m, d);
MonthDay start = MonthDay.of(3, 20);
MonthDay end = MonthDay.of(6, 20);
if (md.isAfter(start) && md.isBefore(end)) {
    System.out.println(true);
} else {
    System.out.println(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   1.  if else {
    ----
    } else{
    ----
    }

   2. if else {
    ---
    } if else{

    }else
```

The above two construct are absolutely legal. But following construct goes wrong:

```
   if else {
    ---

    } else{  ----> GOES WRONG HERE

    }if else
```